# Net names of diff pairs on Altium

Tags: pcb-design, schematics, altium

I have a question about schematics on Altium. When I put a capacitor (or other component) in a diff pair line , the lane after the component loses the diff property and i have to use labels for all the slices produced by the component adition. If I use diferent labels for different names is to annoying when I have to check length matching, but if I use the same net label name then appears ghost lines on the PCB design. Is there any way to put a name for all the net without problems or using labels is the way to do that?

Thank you so much.

[image: The problem.]

[image: My solution.]

[image: Ghost lines produced by my solution.]

Comment: You need to use a different net name - they are not the same nets after all. You can create a "xSignal" from these nets, and apply your routing requirements (e.g. length matching) to these. Never used them, so I can't write an answer.

Comment: I hit the same wall a few years ago with Altium 17. The only solution for me was to use different net names, unfortunately *(To decrease the visual complexity I used very low text heights for them)*. I don't know if anything has changed on newer versions (because I hate Altium starting from 18) but I think still this the only solution as Altium requires the diff net names to have _P and _N suffixes.